# JMenuItem unwanted tint

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am creating a program that uses both a JMenuBar and a JPopupMenu with a windows LaF (look and feel).

Here is the simplified LaF code:

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionBackground", Color.BLUE);
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionForeground", Color.WHITE);
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", Color.BLACK);
    UIManager.put("MenuItem.foreground", Color.WHITE);
```

MouseListener code:

```
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem) {
        JMenuItem i = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
        i.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.background"));
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem) {
        JMenuItem i = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
        i.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("MenuItem.selectionBackground"));
    }
}
```

I am trying to remove what seems to be a windows LaF artifact that tints the selected JMenuItem white. When I disable the components they no longer receive said tint.

I can't seem to find any mention of this effect online, and it also appears to show only slightly on JMenus (might be the darker color though) when their popup is active.

**Edit:** I believe it called "HOT" in java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent:

**eg:** [oldValue=NORMAL; / newValue=HOT;]

Example:

[image: example]

**1st and 2nd image:** show JMenu with no tint.

**3rd image:** this is the effect I'm talking about.

**4th image:** when I'm not hovering over JMenuItem

**5th image:** this is what it shows when I setEnabled to false, I want it to look like this without disabling it.

Does anyone know how to remove this?

Comment: I created a [mcve] with the above constraints (Note that you don't include `UIManager.put("Menu.___")` in your post) and couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think you're missing the point, its not about the code its a Windows 7 Swing look and feel effect that mimics the effect windows 7 shows on its GUI and I want to disable it, I can '@Override' the 'paintComponent' method but I don't know how to redraw the text, arrow and icon in the exact same fashion. I added the colors to distinguish the effect and supplied the simplified code to show that I'm not adding the effect.

Comment: 1) Create a [mcve] to remove any doubt of incorrect reproduction. 2) Is it only on Win 7, or on 8 and 10 too?

Comment: add this line UIManager.put("Menu.opaque", false); to LaF code

Comment: You don't need the code in MouseListener. By setting the UIManager properties, you've already done those. Remove the code in MouseListener.